# The method inside runOnUiThread

Tags: java, android

I just started learning Java and Android few weeks ago, and i found out having trouble while trying to understand the code down below.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    Runnable setData(String _denso, String _data) {
        denso = _denso;
        data = _data;
        return this;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {

    }
}.setData(data.getSymbologyDenso(), data.getData())
```

The part im having trouble understanding is how setData method works, why is it able to be used after the Instance Initialization Block.
It would be helpful if anyone can give me a hand on understanding this part of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating an instance of an anonymous class, then you're invoking the `setData` method on said instance. `setData` return the instance itself, which in turn gets passed as the argument of `runOnUiThread`.

Anyway, it seems like `setData` returns `this` only to make ends meet: I don't think it is a good solution. If you need to initialize that `Runnable`, it may be a good idea to make it a (possibly inner) class with a proper constructor.

PS: you should follow the Java Code Conventions (do not use an underscore a parameter's first character).

Comment: Thanks for your reply know and it helps found out that i havent really touch on what an anonymous class is.